# How to make my Spring Batch step executions end with statuses other than COMPLETED

Tags: spring-batch

Requirement:
Manager doesn’t want multiple instance of the job in the job instance and Job execution tables. He wants just one instance though multiple executions are fine.

Implications: 
The job cannot end with a batch status of COMPLETED since such an instance can never be restarted.

My approach: 
I try to end the job with a batch status of STOPPED so that the next run of the job runs the same instance that was ran previously. (Note that if the job fails then there’s no issue since a failed instance can be re-run).  I plan to have no parameter for the job so that the default instance created on each run matches the instance that already exists in the database (job instance table). In this way, I don’t have to worry about passing any parameter to the job when restarting since there’s just one instance and it has no differentiating parameters.

Issues: 
If all steps complete and the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION gets updated to COMPLTED for all such steps, I cannot rerun this same job instance anymore even if I manage to have the job execution end with a status of STOPPED.  I get   the message:  All steps already completed or no steps configured for this job.

I know what the message means but I’m trying to have all steps end in a status other than completed so that whenever I re-run my single instance, those steps can be re-run as well rather than getting that above message. 
I am aware that a step execution status can be used to derive the job execution status. For example, if a step ends in STOPPED, you can use that status to instruct the job to end in STOPPED as well through the ,    ,  or  elements. This is not what I am looking for as I already know how to work with them unless there’s a way to do them such that they affect what’s updated in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION   table.

In that table, I want the steps to end with STOPPED  if they are successful rather than with COMPLETED.  Any ideas? Is it possible to achieve this in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

TO set the step execution status -

```
StepExecution stepExecution = StepSynchronizationManager.getContext().getStepExecution();
stepExecution.setExitStatus("XYZ")
```

an example of 'end on' in step

```
<batch:step id="step1">
    <batch:tasklet ref="aaaTasklet"/>
    <batch:end on="END1" />
    <batch:end on="XYZ"/>
    <batch:next on="*" to="step2" />
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="aaaTaskletListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:step>

<batch:step id="step2">
.
.
.
</batch:step>
```

Batch Schema - 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
search

```
<xsd:element name="end">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to make sense. I will try this approach and give the result for others who may be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Jobs (as steps) must be completed to let spring-batch correctly manage job's lifecycle.

The way to allow running the same job multiple times is to use a an extra job parameter to make every job different from others; you can use a `JobParametersIncrementer` or just add a new parameter like `startDate = new Date()`.
IMO your way should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks Bellabax. It seems I'll have no option but to have multiple job instances. Are you aware of any way to clean up the infrastructure tables periodically? Our batches will run 8 times a day so these tables could grow very larger for us over time.

Comment: a job scheduled with quartz :)

Answer (score 2):

When getting the "All steps already completed or no steps configured for this job." it might be that you are running the same job with exactly the same params.

To solve this easily you can just add a timestamp to the JobParams like this:

```
@Test
public void importFilesTest() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("timestamp",
                    System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. i wanted to restart the job on failure. I used decider to take flow decision in batch job configuration file.

When I intentionally fail/stop the job , and rerun with corrected data- then job directly jumped to decider without re running the Step which I want to rerun in case of failure. I did the research on it and came to conclusion that you can not re run the step with same job parameter, even job was failed/stopped. Since in Batch Job table, the status of Step is COMPLETED. hence as per spring batch life cycle, Job will start from the point it was failed. In my case, that point was decider. Hence job was running from decider to correctly manage batch job life cycle.
Hope this is helpful for you.